# Disable user interaction but allow tap gesture in UIViewController

Tags: ios, objective-c, swrevealviewcontroller

I would like to disable the user interaction on the entire view but also allow the tap gesture on the view. Let say there is a menu above the main view and if the user taps on the main view again the rear menu disappears. However all other interaction with the main view should be disabled as long as the menu is shown. 
Here is how I try to do that: 
I defined the tapGestureRecognizer like this:

```
@interface GroupMasterViewController () <SWRevealViewControllerDelegate>

@property NSMutableArray *groups;
@property (nonatomic, strong) UITapGestureRecognizer *tapGestureRecognizer;

@end
```

In my ViewDidLoad method I have this:

```
self.tapGestureRecognizer = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self.revealViewController action:@selector(rightRevealToggle:)];
[self.view addGestureRecognizer:self.tapGestureRecognizer];
self.tapGestureRecognizer.enabled = NO;
```

And in the delegate method which gets fired when the menu opens or closes:

```
- (void)revealController:(SWRevealViewController *)revealController willMoveToPosition:(FrontViewPosition)position
{
    if (position == FrontViewPositionLeftSide) {
        self.tapGestureRecognizer.enabled = YES;
        self.view.userInteractionEnabled = NO;
        self.tabBarController.tabBar.userInteractionEnabled = NO;
    }
    else if (position == FrontViewPositionLeft){
        self.tapGestureRecognizer.enabled = NO;
        self.view.userInteractionEnabled = YES;
        self.tabBarController.tabBar.userInteractionEnabled = YES;

    }
}
```

The Problem is that the tapGestureRecognizer does not work anymore if I disable the user interaction.

Thank you in advance for any help.

Comment: you are disabling the whole view so that UITapGestureRecognizer will not work.Please make the views as the subviews of the main view and enable and disable the view you want

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It would be conflict if you try to enable `tapGestureRecogizer` while disabling user interaction, so this is the most straight-forward solution in my honest opinion: Instead of turning off user interaction of the whole view, you should do that to each of the views that you want to not response to touches. For example:

```
- (void)revealController:(SWRevealViewController *)revealController willMoveToPosition:(FrontViewPosition)position
{
    if (position == FrontViewPositionLeftSide) {
        self.tapGestureRecognizer.enabled = YES;
        self.button1.userInteractionEnabled = NO;
        self.button2.userInteractionEnabled = NO;
        self.tabBarController.tabBar.userInteractionEnabled = NO;
    }
    else if (position == FrontViewPositionLeft){
        self.tapGestureRecognizer.enabled = NO;
        self.button1.userInteractionEnabled = YES;
        self.button2.userInteractionEnabled = YES;
        self.tabBarController.tabBar.userInteractionEnabled = YES;

    }
}
```

Comment: What would you do If you have a table view and it should close the menu if the user taps on that table view. If I disable the user interaction for the table view the tap does not work anymore.

Comment: You just need to disable interaction on the table view, but add the gesture recognizer to the main view of the view controller, i.e. `self.view`. Just so you can still tap on the view without affecting the table view.

Answer (score 1):

I think it is not possible to disable user interaction and then expect some user interaction events. You may show `progress bar` for a particular event to prevent user interaction.